# Quota cannot impose its rules!

Tags: quota

For several times I tried to set quota on /home in CentOS 6.5 on Vbox
but after remount `/home` and `quotacheck` terminal report this:

> quotacheck: Cannot remount filesystem mounted on /home read-only so counted values might not be right. please stop all programs writing to filesystem or use -m flag to force checking.

I use `-m` option and increase `/home` permission up to 777 but everything remains the same.
This is a screenshot of my terminal:
[image]

Now what can I do? and what causes this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `chmod 777 /home` is a problem—you shouldn't do that. Change it back. Stuff like that should never be needed when running as `root`: `root` ignores permission bits.

Other than that, it's just telling you that it's not possible for it to verify the correctness of quota accounting if the filesystem is modified while its checking. Basically, the way it works is by scanning through all the files on the filesystem, totaling up their size (by user/group). So, given three files (A, B, and C), it might check A to get its size, user, and group, then B, then C. If midway through that (while it's adding in B, for example) someone adds 10MB to A, `quotacheck` won't know that happened. So it'll have a sum that is 10MB too small—and thus complain about a quota accounting error when there isn't really one. It also might be possible to corrupt the quote accounting file, depending.

Normally you'd run `quotacheck` on boot, before starting to use the filesystem (your distro's boot scripts probably already do this). Alternatively, you'd bring it down to single user so there aren't any users trying to modify their files.